# handling php code

Tags: php

morning. I am wanting to take all segments of php code out of a file located on my local server. Problem is i dont seem to be getting anywhere, no php errors just browser errors.

```
$file_contents = "<xmp>".file_get_contents("../www.cms.actwebdesigns.co.uk2/pageIncludes/instalation/selectMainPages.php")."</xmp>";

if(preg_match_all("#<\?php((?!\?>).)*#is", $file_contents, $matches))
{
    foreach($matches[0] as $phpCode)
    {
        $code = "<xmp>".$phpCode."\n?></xmp>";
    }
}
echo "dsds";
?>
```

could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Baaaaad question.  Consider taking some time to explain cause, effect, errors, and intent.  Baa.

Comment: for the past 14months i've been working on a plug n play CMS (takes 45secs to install and your away!) but i want to go up a knotch by installing to a pre made php website. So i need to try and separate data.

error 

This web page is not available.

The web page at null might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

  More information on this error
Below is the original error message

Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to tokenize the PHP script using the Tokenizer extension:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php

The extensions is built into PHP since PHP v4.3.0.

```
$tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents($file));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php

Comment: Not sure how to use this. Puts all code into an array. For me to use it wouldn't i have to implode it or something then im back to square one?

Comment: you can loop through and remove all those which are not PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

working with this:

```
$file_contents = token_get_all(file_get_contents("../www.cms.actwebdesigns.co.uk2/logged.php"));
$start=0;
$end=0;
$segmentArray = array();
foreach($file_contents as $key => $token)
{
    $tokenName = token_name($key);
    if($start==0 && $end==0 && $tokenName=="T_OPEN_TAG")
    {
        $start=1;
    }
    if(start==1 && $end==0 && $tokenName!="T_CLOSE_TAG")
    {
        $entryNo = count($segmentArray);
        $segmentArray[$entryNo][] = $token;
    }
    if($tokenName=="T_CLOSE_TAG")
    {
        $start=0;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Running into a problem. Alot of the token names are returning UNKNOWN. any one know why?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to use this. Puts all code into an array. For me to use it wouldn't i have to implode it or something then im back to square one?

Comment: This is either a comment on an answer or you should just edit your question.